# error when adding image to wpf toolbar button

Tags: wpf, vb.net, toolbar

I am getting this error: "value does not fall within the expected range" when I try to add code to add an image for a button in a wpf app in VB.net. I don't seem to know what to do or what is wrong? Here is the XAML code that gives the error:

```
<ToolBarTray Height="33" Name="ToolBarTray1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <ToolBar Background="Cyan" Height="33" Band="1" BandIndex="1" ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True">
                            <Button><Image Source="new.bmp"/></Button>
                        </ToolBar> 
                    </ToolBarTray>
```

The part that is underlined showing the error is `<Image Source="new.bmp"/>` . Someone tell me what is not right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your project is set up but read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx